# Main View gets dark when coming back from Background

Tags: ios, view

I am using RouteMe's library and services to display maps.
The main ViewController holds an `*RMMapView` that inherits from UIView. Basically it just fills up with tiles.
When my app goes to background, and after a while, after other apps are loaded into memory usually, comes back to foreground, The main mapView goes completely black and I can't see anything except for my UI. 
(I guess due to lack of memory)

How can I prevent that from happening ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you cant prevent a Memory warning from happening, however if you are 100% sure that you cant handle the memory warning in some view controller and to stop the call to `viewDidUnload` remove the implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your view controller

**Please note** that disabling the viewDidUnload is not recommended, you should reflect about your memory usage and present a better memory management technique